# ComboBox with two DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I have a UserControl with a ListView inside the `ItemTemplate` property has a ComboBox i need use two datacontext for this ComboBox

1. ItemsSource DataContext from UserControl
2. SelectedItem DataContext from ListViewItem

### how to achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RelativeSource` in your binding to traverse the Visual Tree to find the `DataContext for UserControl`.

Whereas for `ListViewItem`, you don't need RelativeSource since `Combobox will inherit the DataContext of its parent which is ListViewItem` itself. Your structure would look somewhat like this -

```
<UserControl>
   <ListView>
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.CollectionSource,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                           AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                         SelectedItem="{Binding YourItemHere}"/>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
</UserControl>
```